# How can i prove that, $\{(a,b):-1<a<1,-1\le b\le 1\}\subset\mathbb R^2$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> How can i prove that, $\{(a,b):-1<a<1,-1\le b\le 1\}\subset\mathbb R^2$ is connected ?

it looks obvious, since the set is path-connected and this implies that it is connected, but is there a rigorous proof of connectedness (not path-connectedness), s.t. it cannot be divided into 2 disjoint open sets?

Comment: Write it as $(-1,1)\times [-1,1]$ a product of two sets, and show each of the factors is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea: your set is

$$X:=(-1,1)\times [-1,1]$$

(1) Check that $\;(0,0)\in X\;$

(2) Prove that

$$\;\forall (a,b)\in X\;,\;a\neq0\;,\;\;y=\frac bax\;,\;\;0\le x\le a$$

is a line segment joining the point with the origin. Show something similar when $\;a=0\;$

(3) Deduce that $\;X\;$ is path-connected, and thus...

Comment: i wanted to avoid to prove it indirectly (with path-connectedness), but this looks nice. I think Daniel Fischer's idea would be sufficient.

Comment: Indeed so, but both answers still require a little something else: in Daniel's case you have to prove that the product of two connected sets is a connected set in the product topology, and in my case you have to prove that path-connected $\;\implies\;$ connected. A matter of taste.